# If a cell's value is found on another column, how to return the cell's value from another column which is on same row with the synced cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My Excel table is looking like this.

```
A column is the one that I want to fill in with correct data. 
B column is where the lookup values are.
C column is the one where I want to extract data from. 
D column is where data from B column will be searched.
```

For example, if data from B2 is found on D7 cell, I want to have in A2 the value from C7.

My Countries///My Codes////All Countries//////All Codes

```
                AD        Afghanistan      AF
                AU         Albania         AL
                           Algeria         DZ
                        American Samoa     AS
                           Andorra         AD
                           Angola          AO
                          Anguilla         AI
                         Antarctica        AQ
                    Antigua and Barbuda    AG
                          Argentina        AR
                          Armenia          AM
                           Aruba           AW
                         Australia         AU
                          Austria          AT
                         Azerbaijan        AZ
```

It would be much appreciated your help because I would like to learn as much as I can about excel formulas.

Kind Regards,
Ioan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=INDEX(C$1:C$15,MATCH(B1,D$1:D$15,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Note:

`MATCH()` finds the row.
`INDEX()` grabs the value.

Comment: thanks! it works and this is what I was looking for. I will study more about " match" function.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is right, looks like you need a vlookup, example

B1 would be

=Vlookup(A1,c1:d200,2,0)

B2 would be

=Vlookup(A2,c1:d200,2,0)

And so on

It works like this
Vlookup (value to lookup, range the lookup and return values are in, column number from range you want to return, exact match only (0 or false))

Though Chris's link is more detailed